# SimCity: What to do about radiation?

Tags: simcity-2013

One of my nuclear power plants recently had a meltdown, and now the entire area is covered in radiation.  No buildings are able to flourish there; they all become abandoned due to radiation.  I've waited a pretty long time, and it doesn't seem as if the effects of the radiation are dying down at all?

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the radiation?  Does it dissipate naturally and I just have waited long enough?  Will certain buildings do okay in radioactive areas?